# ExtJS - Form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, submit

I've got code:

```
win = desktop.createWindow({
    id: 'admin-win',
    title: 'Add administration users',
    width: 740,
    height: 480,
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    animCollapse: false,
    constrainHeader: true,
    xtype: 'form',
    bodyPadding: 15,
    url: 'save-form.php',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Field',
        name: 'theField'
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: function () {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if (form.isValid()) {
                form.submit({
                    success: function (form, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.message);
                    },
                    failure: function (form, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result ? action.result.message : 'No response');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

And buttons doesn't work. It creates error - this.up('form') is undefined. How can I call getForm() in such code like that?

UPDATE:
Thanks for really quick reply!
I modified your code for my needs, this is it, and it works with Desktop Example:

```
win = desktop.createWindow({
    id: 'admin-win',
    title: 'Add administration users',
    width: 740,
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    animCollapse: false,
    constrainHeader: true,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        bodyPadding: 15,
        url: 'save-form.php',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Field',
            name: 'theField'
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function () {
                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                if (form.isValid()) {
                    this.up().up().submit({
                        success: function (form, action) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.message);
                        },
                        failure: function (form, action) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result ? action.result.message : 'No response');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Is this your complete code? What desktop.createWindow do? I'm asking this because it seems that you are trying to crete a window but using Ext.form.Panel options.

Comment: It's based on ExtJS Desktop Example. I want to create window with form only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I already said, it seems that you have problems with your code. You are passing Ext.form.Panel options to a Ext.window.Window (I assuming this because the name of the method that you are calling). I'm writing an example with a window for you. Just a moment.

It is ready. Take a look:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'This is a Window with a Form',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{  // the form is an item of the window
        id: 'admin-win',
        title: 'Add administration users',
        width: 740,
        height: 480,
        iconCls: 'icon-grid',
        animCollapse: false,
        constrainHeader: true,
        xtype: 'form',
        bodyPadding: 15,
        url: 'save-form.php',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Field',
            name: 'theField',
            allowBlank: false
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function() {
                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                if (form.isValid()) {
                    form.submit({
                        success: function(form, action) {
                           Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.message);
                        },
                        failure: function(form, action) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result ? action.result.message : 'No response');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert( "Error!", "Your form is invalid!" );
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
}).show();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/vWmmD/

Comment: Thanks :-) I updated my 1st post, because I don't have permission to answer for my topics ;-) I've got to modify your code for my needs.

Comment: You are welcome! As I said, you were indeed passing Ext.form.Panel options to a Ext.window.Window :) ExtJS is very nice. Take a look in its documentation because it is very complete.